# How to validate the Ckeditor using JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I am new in javascript and I am developing a project into CodeIgniter.
Actually, I face a problem into  CKEditor validation.When I fill all field and Click on the submit button then one message show CkEditor is required field But when I again click on the submit button data successfully submitted.

I don't know how to resolve this problem.I already search so many things But my Problem is same. I using this code But this is giving an error getData() is not Defined I don't know what is getdata and where I have to use this.

```
function CheckForm(theForm) 
{
    textbox_data = CKEDITOR.instances.mytextbox.getData();
    if (textbox_data==='')
    {
        alert('please enter a comment');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

change this

```
textbox_data = CKEDITOR.instances.mytextbox.getData();
```

to

```
textbox_data = CKEDITOR.instances['mytextbox'].getData();
```

in `[]` there should be id of the textbox.

**NOTE:** Don't forget to add CKEditor JS.

Comment: Can you explain it a little bit?

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 we have to pass id of textbox in `[]` so that it can be locate and check whether it is empty or not.

Comment: Any difference in both ways and why to use `[]`?

Comment: might be it could not be located id without `[]`

Comment: Property accessors provide access to an object's properties by using the dot notation or the bracket notation.

Comment: @DavidG i told to accept this because i searched a lot and i found this silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I guess might be two mistakes you are doing

1. declared form later and would have written JavaScript before
2. getdata() is simple jQuery function to get anything within CKeditor text box

Please refer complete CKeditor documentation [here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/).

Comment: You can't call jquery methods on CKEditor object `getdata() is simple jquery function`;